# Sending received message back to UI activity, but app stuck

Tags: android, bluetooth, thread-safety

```
static class BluetoothInHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<Bluetooth_dataDisplay> mActivity;

        BluetoothInHandler(Bluetooth_dataDisplay activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            final Bluetooth_dataDisplay thizz = mActivity.get();
            if (thizz == null) return;
            if (msg.what == thizz.handlerState) {
               String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
               thizz.myLabel.setText(readMessage);


           }
        }//end of handle message


 }//end of Bluetoothin handler


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_datadisplay);
        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);

        mMyHandler = new BluetoothInHandler(this);



    }//end oncreate



@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  
        String MAC = getIntent().getStringExtra("MAC");
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
        ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
        t.start();

    }

//Setting Up a Connecting Client
private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
   // private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket temp = null;
        bluetoothDevice = device;


        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {

            temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothSocket = temp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel any discovery as it will slow down the connection

        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


        try {

            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            Log.e("bluetooth socket",".connect");
            mmOutputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

            //beginListenForData();
            Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, "Connected with Device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

          handler.post(new Runnable() {

               public void run() {

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                   int bytes;

                   // Keep looping to listen for received messages
                   while (true) {
                       try {
                           bytes = mmInputStream.read(buffer);          
                           String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                           // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                           mMyHandler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
            //beginListenForData();
            //Log.e("begin", "begindata");

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
                Log.e("click6", "blueclose");
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Trying to send data from thread back to UI activity but my app just stuck. :( I don't know what wrong with it. Please help. No error and no crashes of app. I had tried runnableUIthread as well. It didn't work too. So I don't know what to do now.

[image: log.e(test,handler)]

Comment: Did you try to step through your code in your debugger? If so, what did you find? If not, you should try it.

Comment: @takendarkk hi where should I put the breakpoint?

Comment: Where did you use ConnectingThread ?

Comment: You are use Handler handler = new Handler() to send msg and  you want to receive msg in mMyHandler = new BluetoothInHandler(this).

Comment: @tinysunlight I used it on the onResume. Just edited my post with Onresume

Comment: Just pass mHandler into Thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
static class BluetoothInHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<Bluetooth_dataDisplay> mActivity;

        BluetoothInHandler(Bluetooth_dataDisplay activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //change 3
            Log.e("test","handleMessage");
            final Bluetooth_dataDisplay thizz = mActivity.get();
            if (thizz == null) return;
            if (msg.what == thizz.handlerState) {
               String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
               thizz.myLabel.setText(readMessage);


           }
        }//end of handle message


 }//end of Bluetoothin handler

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  
        String MAC = getIntent().getStringExtra("MAC");
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
        ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice,mMyHandler );
        t.start();

    }

//Setting Up a Connecting Client
private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
   // private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
    Handler handler;
    public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device,Handler mHandler) {
        handler = mHandler
        BluetoothSocket temp = null;
        bluetoothDevice = device;


        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {

            temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothSocket = temp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel any discovery as it will slow down the connection

        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


        try {

            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            Log.e("bluetooth socket",".connect");
            mmOutputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

            //beginListenForData();
            Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, "Connected with Device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
           //change 7
          //handler.post(
            new Runnable() {

             public void run() {

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                   int bytes;

                   // Keep looping to listen for received messages
                   while (true) {
                        //change 1
                       try{
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                       }catch(Throwable e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                       try {
                           bytes = mmInputStream.read(buffer);          
                           String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                           // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                            //change 4;
                           handler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                          //change 6
                          Log.e("test","6")
                         //change 2
                         e.printStackTrace();

                           break;
                       }catch(Throwable e1){
                          //change 5;
                          Log.e("test","5")
                       }
                   }
               }.run();
           //});
            //beginListenForData();
            //Log.e("begin", "begindata");

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
                Log.e("click6", "blueclose");
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice,mHandler); mHandler is in red the error said it cannot resolve symbol

Comment: new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice,mMyHandler), not new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice,mHandler);

Comment: Hi same thing. The app just stuck there

Comment: Did you get some error print in logcat? Or can you try to debug it?

Comment: Hi No error from log cat. :( I try put a breakpoint at this line mMyHandler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage) when I step over it just go back to bytes = mmInputStream.read(buffer);  then back to mMyHandler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage)

Comment: I added change 3-6.And can you log some error to confirm your logcat is  working fine?

Comment: hi what do you mean by log some error to confirm my log cat is working fine? Thanks for being patience.

Comment: Hi erm  I run the code with the added change and it just stuck after this line  bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.e("bluetooth socket",".connect"); and also my bluetooth device is connected.

Comment: Change handler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget(); to  Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(); handler.sendMessage(msg);

Comment: Send a message after mMyHandler = new BluetoothInHandler(this); to watch whether it can reach Log.e("test","handleMessage");

Comment: I posted the log cat photo. Please check. The Log.e("test,handlemessage)" come first then it connect the device. Then app stuck again.

Comment: Are you sure you code run to handler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();?

Comment: ?what do you mean by that. :( Is it possible if I send you the code? So you can look at it. :(

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmfra2p2a18mjti/BluetoothApp.rar?dl=0 Here is the zip file. If you can help please. Thank you!!

Comment: @Spotty Try remove handler.post().

Comment: When you use handler.post(a) ,a get into row. When you sendMsg1,...,000 in a ,msg 1,...1000 get into row.But a is runing, msgs should wait till it stop.

Comment: public void run() { this part it said ; is expected (error) Is it because I got two public void run() in the connected thread?

Comment: I edited. Just remove handler.post() and add run() on new Runnable().@Spotty  Or you can just remove new Runnable and put the code in it out.

Comment: Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException at this part of the code bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.e("bluetooth socket",".connect");
                mmOutputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                mmInputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

Comment: You have  caught IOException ,why did it say that Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException .You can update you quesition.I have no bluetooth device and I can't test it for you. You should help youself.

Comment: Hi I put the try catch this way   try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.e("bluetooth socket",".connect");
                mmOutputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                mmInputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }